# how to call a class from the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, interceptor

Basically, Am trying to call a model class from the axis response. I want to show a modal popup instead of alert below code. can anyone help how to call the modal class from Axios interceptor function? thanks in advance

```
import React, { Component}  from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Modals  from '../components/modalAlerts/modalalerts'
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://someurl',
    timeout: 15000,
}); 

instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = //sequrity token will be here
instance.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {

    return config;
  }, function (error) {

    alert(error)
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
instance.interceptors.response.use(function (config) {

    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error)
    if(error.response){
        if(error.response.status === 401||error.response.status === 403 ){
            localStorage.clear()
            alert(error.response.data.message)
        }else if(error.response.status === 404){
            console.log("404")
        }else if(error.response.status === 400){
           alert(error.response.data.message)
        }else{
            alert("something went wrong. Please try after sometime..!")
        }
    }else{
        alert("server not found")
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
export default instance;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do some thing like below

You need a Boolean flag for this. Initialise Boolean flag in constructor using `this.state`

```
  constructor(props){
      super(props){
          this.state = {
              callModal: false,
              errorMessage: ""
          }
      }
  }
```

In the below code you need to change regular function to arrow function in order to access `this` inside

```
 axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {      
    return response;
  }, error => {
    // set callModal flag to true using this.setState
    this.setState({
        callModal: true,
        errorMessage: error
    });
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Or bind the function so that `this` is accessible

```
   axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {      
    return response;
  }.bind(this), function (error) {
    // set callModal flag to true using this.setState
    this.setState({
        callModal: true,
        errorMessage: error
    });
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }.bind(this));
```

Now in render call Modal class

```
     render(){
         const { callModal, errorMessage } = this.state;
         return(){
            <div>
                {callModal && <ModalComponent errorMessage={errorMessage} />
            </div>
         }
     }
```

To make the same functionality work for the second time you need to set callModal to false when user clicks on cancel button in modal using callback

Comment: It is modal popup but not model popup. OP seems mispelled model instead of modal. This solution would work in his way

Comment: Nope I am answering in my mobile so I don’t have right double quotes in my mobile keyboard:)

Comment: its not working @think-twice , but thanks for the responce

Comment: Since you haven’t provided much code I gave you a detailed hint to make things work. My answer will help you achieve what you want. You need to understand the steps I explained and implement in your code which you haven’t shared. If it isn’t working which means you must be doing something wrong

Comment: I just updated my code u can check it once @think-Twice